# Generate html divs using javascript from based on database

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to generate divs using javascript from database?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific and/or show some code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need AJAX for the same. So you need to make the PHP script output:

```
<?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $data);
  $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `table`");
  while (false != ($dat = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo '<li>' . $dat[0] . '</li>';
  }
?>
```

And in your HTML, using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$("#list").load("db.php");
```

And your HTML should be:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>Loading data...</li>
</ul>
```